# ASP.NET MVC 5 Map model name with database column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have got model as:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    }
```

But the database columns are user_id, user_name, password, email, mobile_no.

How do I map every model property with the column names.

I know there's `ColumnAttribute` for this but i don't want to make changes in all models. So is there any generic method to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why the model names can't be the same as the database names?

Comment: do you use any ORM?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework 6.